# Указатели, небольшое недопонимание

Tags: c, указатели

Изучаю указатели на указатели в Си и возникли небольшие "непонятки".

```
int **pp, *p, A = 10, B = 20;
p = &A, pp = &p; /* сейчас *p = **pp = 10 */
*pp = &B; /* теперь *p = **pp = 20 */
```

Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, почему можно делать так, как мы сделали в строчке 3? Я экспериментально определил, что `*pp` и `p` лежат по одному адресу (но для вас это вряд ли новость), но почему так происходит я не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Ну, `*pp` — это переменная, лежащая по указателю `pp`. Её тип `int*`, и её, понятно, можно изменять точно так же, как и любую другую переменную.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int **pp, *p, A = 10, B = 20;
p = &A
```

В `p` записан адрес переменной `A`.

```
pp = &p;
```

В `pp` записан адрес переменной `p`. Значит, `*pp` - это по сути переменная `p`, в которой хранится адрес `A`. Ну, а `**pp` - это то же, что и `*p`, т.е. значение по адресу, хранящемуся в `p` - а там хранится адрес `A`. Значит, это значение `A`, т.е. 10.

```
*pp = &B;
```

Вспомним, что в `pp` хранится адрес переменной `p`, так что `*pp` по сути получается тем же, что и `p`. Т.е. запись в `*pp` сейчас - когда в `pp` хранится адрес `p` - то же самое, что запись в переменную `p`. А записываем мы туда адрес переменной `B`.

А дальше применимы все те же рассуждения, что были сделаны выше, когда в `p` хранился адрес переменной `A`...

Comment: `*pp` - это то же, что и `*p` — вы точно уверены?

Comment: **pp имелось в виду, как мне кажется

Comment: @VladD Да, спасибо, конечно, описка. copy-paste... :)